# understanding this form of for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop, linked-list

I have come across this For loop in c and I am struggling to make sense of it
this is the loop
Context: loop is going over a linked list

```
POINTER **prev=head, *curr, *next;

 for(curr = *head; curr; prev = &curr->link, curr = curr->link)
```

To my knowledge I can gather that `curr` will begin at the head of the list.
what is `curr;` does this just mean the pointer current is not NULL? normally in that section it would be something like `i < 5;`

And lastly,  `prev = &curr->link, curr = curr->link` - I have never seen a comma separating the incrementor (if thats what it is) I also dont understand what that section is doing.

Could someone possibly break this loop down for me to help me understand what is going on?

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the loop work?

Comment: Someone might need to explain to me how `prev = &curr->link` takes the address of `curr`. Looks like it's taking the address of `->link`, which is the next link??

Comment: yeah its from a bubble sort on a linked list - it does work

Comment: `prev` points to the pointer that points to `curr`. This makes it possible to remove `curr` from the list or to insert something in the list before `curr` just by uodating `*prev`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is `curr;` does this just mean the pointer current is not NULL?

Correct.  The second clause of a `for` loop is the *controlling expression*, and the loop continues as long as the controlling expression does not compare equal to 0.  Since `curr` is a pointer, it will only be equal to 0 if it is a NULL pointer.

> And lastly, `prev = &curr->link, curr = curr->link` - I have never seen a comma separating the incrementor (if that's what it is) I also don't understand what that section is doing.

The comma here in the third clause of the `for` loop is an instance of the *comma operator*.  This operator evaluates its left operand, discards the value of that operand, then evaluates the right operand.  In this context, using the comma operator allows us to assign a value to two variables in a single expression.

Specifically, this expression sets the `prev` pointer to point to the address of the `link` member of the current node, then sets the `curr` pointer to point to the next node in the list.  The reason for `prev` being a pointer-to-pointer is presumably to allow either the current node to be removed or for a new node to be inserted before the current node, while also allowing for the special case of `*head` potentially being updated.

Answer (score 3):

Compact, isn't it? Beautiful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop#1972:_C/C++

```
for (initialization; condition; increment/decrement)
    statement
```

**Initialization**

```
curr = *head;
```

Is executed once at the start of the loop. `curr` is the iterator, and it starts at whatever `head` points too.

**Condition**

`curr;`
True if `curr` is not `NULL`. False if `curr` is `NULL` (a peculiarity in C where `0` or `NULL` equate to False, and anything not `0` or `NULL` equates to True). The condition is checked at the beginning of each loop iteration. If true then the loop goes around again. If False, the loop exits.

**Increment/Decrement**

Here you encounter the odd looking comma operator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

This part of the loop is executed at the end of the loop iteration, before the Condition is checked for the next iteration. Using the comma operator, two operations have been squeezed in here:

Set `prev` to be the `curr` link (that's what makes sense to me, though I think something else may be meant by `prev` here):

```
prev = &curr->link
```

Now set `curr` to be the next link in the list:

```
curr = curr->link
```

The link list is thus traversed:

- Initialization: start `curr` at `head`
- Condition: test if `curr` has reached the end (i.e. `NULL`)
- Loop
- Increment/Decrement: move `curr` to the next link; keep the previous link (what was `curr`) in `prev`
- Condition: ...
- Loop
- Increment/Decrement: ...
- ...

Comment: Though I can't tell you if it's achieving what it's meant to. The assignment of `prev` looks suspicious. And I see no reference to `*next`, even though it's declared.

Comment: *next is used for the sort